# jQuery change source of <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have this script in my `admin.blade.php` file.

```html
<img src="#" id="editThumbnail">
```

I want to change the source with JQuery. Here is my script.

```js
var photo = data.user.photo;
$("#editThumbnail").attr("src","{{asset('profile-photos/"+photo+"')}}")
```

For example, `photo` variable has value `"marc.jpg"`. But, the photo won't appear. Here is the error from the browser.
`GET http://localhost:8000/profile-photos/$quot;+photo+&quot; (404 Not Found)`

I have no idea how is this happen. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You have tried something of this:
var path = "{{asset('profile-photos/')}}";
var photo = path + data.user.photo;
$("#editThumbnail").attr("src",photo);

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but your answer is also clever and practical. It's just like do "concat" to the image source into one variable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just use `$("#editThumbnail").attr("src","{{ asset('profile-photos') }}/" + photo)`

Comment: Is this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933167/how-can-i-test-if-a-link-is-valid-in-javascript-or-jquery/59933245#59933245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using template strings concept of JavaScript

```
$("#editThumbnail").attr("src","{`asset('profile-photos/${photo}')`}")
```

Try something like the above.

Comment: Oh My God, many thanks for you. I have never known if JavaScript can do that.

Comment: welcome! Template strings concept is very useful to evaluate the dynamic value into strings. Do take time to study it! All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("#editThumbnail").attr("src","<?php echo asset('profile-photos/') ?>photo");
```